# objectInstance.Property.Method() Invocation in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm learning ADO.NET and here is an example of method call from [MS Documnetation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapter-datatable-and-datacolumn-mappings):

```csharp
workAdapter.TableMappings.Add("AuthorsMapping", "Authors");
```

Where `workAdapter` in an instance of `DataAdapter` class, `TableMappings` its property, and `Add` its method. I have never seen method being invoked in this way. I wasn't able to find an answer here nor in the documentation. Need help understanding this.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand here with regard to the method call? I mean, the `Add` just adds something (a table mapping) to the table mappings of the workAdapter instance...

Comment: This is pretty common. It's just fetching the value of the property, and calling `Add` on the result. What aspect of this is confusing?

Comment: I have never seen before method being called on the property of the class. So far I've only seen it being called like `ClassName.MethodName()`, but never `ClassName.PropertyName.MethodName()`.

Answer (score 0):

Properties and methods are invoked this way a lot. You can chain as many together as you like and it makes sense to do so if you only need to use each one once. Any time you could assign something to a variable and then access a member via that variable, you can access it for what you originally assigned. If you have these types:

```cs
public class Thing
{
    public Stuff Stuff { get; set; }
}

public class Stuff
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

then you could do this:

```cs
var s = new Stuff();
var t = new Thing { Stuff = s };

s.DoSomething();
t.Stuff.DoSomething();
```

In those last two lines, `s` refers to the same object as `t.Stuff` so you can call the same `DoSomething` method on both.

Comment: Understood. One question. Is your code pseudocode, since I also didn't some curly brackets used when instantiating an object? The usual syntax is `ClassName objectName = new ClassName(var parameter);`. I'm seeing for the first time `ClassName objectName = new ClassName(var parameter) { // Some code };`